# H2 connection error using Geotools

Tags: java, spatial-database, geotools, h2gis

I am using geotools (v 17.0) to connect to a H2 database (v 1.4.193) table. My h2 maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.193</version>
</dependency>
```

The H2 database is running in server mode. I set up my table like this (using the browser based console):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mySchema;
CREATE TABLE mySchema.point
(
    the_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    the_geom GEOMETRY
);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX spatial_idx_point ON mySchema.point(the_geom);
```

My database connection:

```
// connection parameter
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap();
params.put( "dbtype", "h2");
params.put( "host", "myHost");
//params.put( "schema", "mySchema");
params.put( "port", 9092);
params.put( "database", "myDB");
params.put( "user", "sa");
params.put( "passwd", "");

// create connection
DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
System.out.println("dataStore.getNames() -> " + dataStore.getNames());
FeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource("POINT");
FeatureStore featureStore = (FeatureStore) featureSource;
```

**With** the **schema parameter** enabled I get this error:

> java.io.IOException: Schema 'POINT' does not exist.   at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.ensureEntry(ContentDataStore.java:620)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:393)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:360)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:103)
>     at db_connector.H2Connection.setFeatureStore(H2Connection.java:49)
>     at db_connector.DbConnection.(DbConnection.java:25)   at
>   db_connector.H2Connection.(H2Connection.java:17)    at
>   feature.FeatureGenerationStarter.main(FeatureGenerationStarter.java:59)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   db_connector.DbConnection.insertFeatures(DbConnection.java:53)    at
>   feature.FeatureGenerationStarter.main(FeatureGenerationStarter.java:60)

The pritln results in:

```
dataStore.getNames() -> []
```

**Without** the **schema parameter** enabled I get the following error:

> 2017-04-25T13:27:55.441+0200  **WARNING  Failure occurred while looking
>   up the primary key** with finder:
>   org.geotools.jdbc.HeuristicPrimaryKeyFinder@27912e3
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabelle "POINT" nicht gefunden **Table
>   "POINT" not found; SQL statement: SELECT "THE_ID" FROM "POINT" WHERE
>   0=1** [42102-193]     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5389)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1257)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1897)     at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2045)     at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1891)    at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1709)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1697)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:445)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)     at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)  at
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:263)   at
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624)     at
>   org.h2.command.CommandRemote.prepare(CommandRemote.java:68)   at
>   org.h2.command.CommandRemote.(CommandRemote.java:45)    at
>   org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.prepareCommand(SessionRemote.java:494)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
>     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:73)    at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.HeuristicPrimaryKeyFinder.createPrimaryKey(HeuristicPrimaryKeyFinder.java:140)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.HeuristicPrimaryKeyFinder.getPrimaryKey(HeuristicPrimaryKeyFinder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.CompositePrimaryKeyFinder.getPrimaryKey(CompositePrimaryKeyFinder.java:52)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getPrimaryKey(JDBCDataStore.java:1109)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.(JDBCFeatureSource.java:95)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.createFeatureSource(JDBCDataStore.java:955)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:395)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:360)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getFeatureSource(ContentDataStore.java:103)
>     at db_connector.H2Connection.setFeatureStore(H2Connection.java:49)
>     at db_connector.DbConnection.(DbConnection.java:25)   at
>   db_connector.H2Connection.(H2Connection.java:17)    at
>   feature.FeatureGenerationStarter.main(FeatureGenerationStarter.java:59)
>
> 2017-04-25T13:27:55.461+0200  **WARNING  Could not find mapping for
>   'THE_GEOM', ignoring the column and setting the feature type read only**
>   Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource cannot be cast to
>   org.geotools.data.FeatureStore**  at
>   db_connector.H2Connection.setFeatureStore(H2Connection.java:51)   at
>   db_connector.DbConnection.(DbConnection.java:25)    at
>   db_connector.H2Connection.(H2Connection.java:17)    at
>   feature.FeatureGenerationStarter.main(FeatureGenerationStarter.java:59)

The println results in:

```
dataStore.getNames() -> [POINT, SPATIAL_REF_SYS]
```

I had a similar problem with Postgis a while ago where the spatial index had to be adjusted like:

```
CREATE INDEX spatial_idx_point ON mySchema.point USING GIST(geom);
```

Is there something similar for H2? Any suggestions?